# Why length of array type is literal number but length of string type is just NUMBER?

Tags: typescript

I'm studying [type challenges, Length of String](https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/blob/master/questions/298-medium-length-of-string/README.md) and found that length of string type is just `number` but length of array is a specific number.

```js
type LengthOfArray<T extends unknown[]> = T["length"];
type LengthOfString<T extends string> = T["length"];

type arrayLength = LengthOfArray<[1, 2, 3]>; // 3
type stringLength = LengthOfString<"123">; // number;
```

How can I understand this issue? What is the reason that TS consider length of string as just `number` ?

Comment: See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34692

Comment: You can also achieve the length of a string as a specific numberic type via a recursive type https://tsplay.dev/NrKLzm

Answer (score 1):

There is not really a great answer to this other than, because they didn't implement it.

Likely, the reason why they strictly typed array lengths was to better support tuples. In your example, using `[1,2,3]` as a type is considered a tuple, which is always fixed in length. Tuple lengths were probably seen as significantly important because validating a tuple's length is pretty common practice.

On the other hand, I can't think of a good use-case for validating an already constant string's length. I'm sure people have been tripped up by this, but it's safe to say it isn't very common.